# Bukkit Plugin Groups Manager is not working?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bukkit

I have made no changes whatsoever to my config.yml or groups.yml. I set myself as the Owner, which I am, and I restarted the server. Then on the server, I typed "/manload". My name did not change color, and all the other players are still able to use the commands.

I know the plugin is working in some respect. Commands like "manuadd" and "manwhois" work perfectly and accurately reflect the .yml files.

I've also checked that all my directories are correct. I only have one world and I'm in "Plugins/GroupManager/worlds/world".

So the plugin is working, but it's not restricting any commands or applying any changes. Why is this? Is there someone other option I have to turn on elsewhere?

Thanks.

EDIT: This is my unchanged
[groups.yml](http://pastebin.com/ShKeSuP5). I didn't even modify this.

This is my [users.yml](http://pastebin.com/f3AmvaRh).
The only changes I made where in the server itself with "/manuadd" I haven't actually edited it with a text editor.

Comment: Your question is not clear, please post your configuration files, as it may contain some invalid markup. (That means your groups.yml and your users.yml in your GroupManager plugin folder), based on what you have stated.

Comment: @aytimothy I just added them. But like I said, I haven't even changed groups, and users I've  only changed with the server itself, so I'm not sure how anything could be wrong. Thanks for being willing to help though.

Comment: Sorry this took so long... I've been rendering an animation for the past few days -- But have you updated your GroupManager? Because mine works... It may be because the server (plugin) does not pick up the new UUID username format.  
EDIT: Otherwise you may want to reinstall the plugin (with the newest version), and remove your old "GroupManager" folder.

Comment: @aytimothy That sounds like a good idea. I'm actually having a lot of trouble with my server now. I can't seem to download a world backup, which I want to do before I try to reset or reload stuff. Anyway, it's a big mess, so I'll fix it when I can. Thanks for the help. =)